# Using a Regex to shorten values

Tags: javascript, regex

I need your help.

The function that I have below will contain multiple matches, so for this example, I have significantly shortened it. My question for the Regex folks on here is, is there a way to shorten the list of matches using some sort of special Regex?

Here are some matches that the function below is checking for:

```
BRIEFING NOTE TO BOSS1
BRIEFING NOTE TO BOSS2
BRIEFING NOTE TO BOSS3
KEY MESSAGES
MEDIA ADVISORY
MEDIA CALL
```

Here is the javascript:

```
function shorten_name(val)
    if (val.match("BRIEFING")) { return "BN" }
    else if (val.match("KEY MESSAGES")) { return "KM" }
    else if (val.match("MEDIA ADVISORY")) { return "MA" }
    else if (val.match("MEDIA CALL")) { return "MC" }
}
```

Comment: What is the output you want?  Something like `BN TO BOSS1`, `BN TO BOSS2`, etc.?

Comment: Now you have 2 problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function (str){ 
    var map = {
        "BRIEFING": "BN",
        "KEY MESSAGES": "KM",
        "MEDIA ADVISORY": "MA",
        "MEDIA CALL": "MC"
    };

    for (key in map){ 
        if (map.hasOwnProperty(key)){
            str = str.replace(new RegExp(key, 'g'), map[key]); 
        }
    } 

   return str; 
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ZqX6T/